# Global filters not returning area name

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

In an Action Filter, 'areaName' gets the correct value when the filter is added to the list of global filters but it always gives null when the filter is added directly to a controller.

```
      public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
      {
        string areaName = (string) filterContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"];
```

Why would global filters work differently?

Comment: is the controller in an area?

Comment: Oh what a fool! I didn't make the controllers in the areas inherit from the controller that the attribute was assigned to! Thanks for your good sense. :)